# Single Page PDF Generation in Python

Tags: python, pdf-generation

I am trying to generate a PDF from plots generated in Python, and so far I have been using PdfPages. There's a lot of info on PdfPages syntax, but I can't seem to figure out how to put my plots on one page - it always makes a page per image.

Also, I want to add a timestamp to the bottom, but `pdf.attach_note()` doesn't seem to show up.

My current code generates a PDF with my 2 images, `plot1` and `plot2`, and saves them to a 2-page PDF without the time stamp, saved as `timestamp`.

```
with PdfPages('{0}.pdf'.format(timestamp)) as pdf:
    fig = plot1
    pdf.savefig(fig)
    fig2 = plot2
    pdf.savefig(fig2)
    pdf.attach_note(timestamp, positionRect=[0,0,100,100])
    plt.close()
```

How do I change this to make a 1-page PDF with the two images, `plot1` and `plot2`, and text `timestamp` at the bottom?

Comment: The overwhelming answer I have found is that PdfPages does not allow for multiple figures on one page, so you have to use subplots.